# Is it possible in IntelliJ to find (possibly) redundant try...catch blocks?

Tags: java, exception, intellij-idea

Here is my use case - I have code in this style

```
try {
    someMethod();
} catch (Exception e) {
    LOGGER.error("exception occurred", e);
   //potentially more code
}
```

and the definition of that method is simply

```
public void someMethod() {
   //do something that doesn't throw an exception
}
```

I'd like to find all the `try...catch` blocks that catch the top level `Exception` class and wrap code that doesn't *explicitly* throw any exception. Is that possible in IntelliJ IDEA?

To clarify, I am aware of the **Redundant 'throws' clause** inspection - this is cleaning up after it.

I am also aware of the **Catch block may ignore exception** inspection - that does not catch the case I've described because the exceptions *are* used in the code. The issue is that the code doesn't actually throw an exception. So, *in theory* it might catch a `NullPointerException` or another unchecked exception, but I'd further analyse if that is indeed useful or not. My goal is to remove all the unneeded exception handling code.

Comment: Catching `Exception` is never *redundant*. It could catch a StackOverflowError, for example, which could be thrown by any line of code at any time. The Java compiler will already complain if you try to catch a checked exception which is not declared as being thrown. I don't know what you're after.

Comment: @Michael it is if it catches the *wrong* exception. Again, this comes after cleaning up redundant `throws` clauses - some code may have been throwing useful exceptions once but not any more. I'd like to better be able to respond to the exceptions that *might* show up. Unfortunately, the catches are very broad and usually just catch `Exception` and the error handling is for something more specific than an NPE or OOM, which impedes the recovery after those. Besides, if `try...catch` is never redundant, why don't we wrap each line in that? That kind of is redundant.

Comment: "if `try...catch` is never redundant" Except that's not what I said. Catching `Exception` will always do something. The control flow is always different for it being there.

Comment: @Michael sure, and do we catch `Exception` on each line of code we write? Do we maybe wrap each method we call into `try..catch(Exception)`? I certainly don't and I don't think I'm wrong. I use this *when needed*.

Comment: You're being obtuse. **If** `Exception` is caught, the control flow is **always** different from when it is not caught. Therefore there is **no** static analyser that can tell you when to remove it. It's not a harmless refactor - it potentially changes the control flow of the entire program. I'm not advocating wrapping every line in a try catch block...... When did I ever say that? I'm saying **if you already have one**, no static analyser can tell you you need to remove it.

Comment: @Michael I want to find them and do analysis myself to see if it's needed or not. There are a lot of times the `catch` blocks can be completely redundant, especially when you have a method that wraps its entire body into a try-catch and the call to the method is wrapped in a try-catch. So, I see absolutely no value in keeping both catch blocks when *by definition* you can't hit both. And sometimes you can't hit either. It's something I want to be able to decide but to do that, I need to *find* these blocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access this warning via the [Inspections](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/inspection-settings.html) menu, and then search for `Overly broad catch block`:

[image]

With this inspection enabled, all the catch blocks are marked which are overly broad. You can also limit the inspection to only warn on `RuntimeException`, `Exception` and `Throwable`:

[image]